# Validity Check: Every function is integrable on its domain, regardless to continuity and differentiablitty.

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-integration

*F(x)* is a function before I attempt to integrate such a function over a certain interval, what I do is check if the interval is a subset of the function's domain, if not then its  not integrable. 
And it doesn't matter if the function includes any types of discontinuities on the interval or includes any indifferentiable points. 
And for indefinite integrals(basically anti-derivatives) they always exist as long as the function exists. 
Additional question: is it possible that the interval a certain function is being integrated on isn't a subset in the domain of the 'new' function (the anti-derivative) thus isn't integrable?

Comment: Your last question is confusing.  The indefinite integral doesn't have a domain, only a variable.

Comment: Well I will try to explain it in a different way, let's say you have a function: f(x) equals 'x' to the power of negative one, if we integrate this over the interval from - 3 to - 6 we won't be able to sub these values into ln(x), however this can be argued against as : 1) ln(-3/-6) exists 2) the result should be ln|x| as both of it and ln(x) have the same derivative.

Comment: I am not sure what your point is. Is it that $\int\frac{dx}{x}=ln(|x|)$ rather than $ln(x)$?

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Consider rationals' characteristic function, i.e. $f(x) = 1$ if $x$ is rational and $f(x) = 0$ when $x$ is irrational. It can be shown to be Riemann non-integrable.